# Why does configparser overwrite my existing files when reading from within an open() loop?

Tags: python-3.x, configparser

I'm trying to manipulate a config file that will look like this:

```
[DEFAULT]
first_api_key = foobar
second_api_key = helloworld
```

Now say I'd like to replace first_api_key with "guccimane" instead of "foobar". Here's the function I'm using to do that:

```
def my_func():
    k, v = "first_api_key", "guccimane"
    file = os.path.join("/example/path", "settings.ini")
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    with open(file, "w") as f:
        config.read(file)
        config["DEFAULT"][k] = v
        config.write(f)
```

However when I run that, second_api_key is removed and I'm left with:

```
[DEFAULT]
first_api_key = foobar
```

However when I change my function slightly to be:

```
def my_func():
    k, v = "first_api_key", "guccimane"
    file = os.path.join("/example/path", "settings.ini")
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read(file)
    with open(file, "w") as f:
        config["DEFAULT"][k] = v
        config.write(f)
```

It works exactly the way I want it to, and it only alters the first_api_key value and the second_api_key remains. Does anyone know why this is getting overwritten?

Comment: Are you aware that `open(file, "w")` truncates the file specified by `file`?

Comment: Also, there's no such this as an "open loop". `open` is just a function that returns an I/O stream. The [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) statement lets you use that I/O stream as a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) to ensure that the stream is closed when you're done. There's no looping involved.

Comment: @Brian I was not aware of that! Python newbie here. So based on those docs, it truncates the file and sets the f variable as the returned I/O stream, and then within the context manager you can handle the data by referencing f? (Apologies if I messed up the verbiage).

Comment: @Brian based on that, my error makes sense. I'm truncating the file and then trying to read it, which of course returns nothing.

Comment: You have it right! You can find more information about the available file mode flags [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

Comment: @Brian Awesome, thanks so much for your time and help :)